# Jacoco with ant not showing coverage

Tags: java, jacoco

I am trying to run Jacaco with ant. When my tests gets executed the coverage is only shown for my Test classes but not for actual code.

My Ant code

```
<target name="test">
        <mkdir dir="${result.report.dir}"/>
        <!-- Wrap test execution with the JaCoCo coverage task -->
        <jacoco:coverage destfile="${result.exec.file}">
            <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="false" haltonerror="false" fork="true" forkMode="perTest" showoutput="true">
                <classpath>
                    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
                        <include name="**/*.jar" />
                    </fileset> 
                    <path refid="compile.class.path"/>
                </classpath>

                <formatter type="xml"/>

                <batchtest fork="true" todir="${result.report.dir}" haltonerror="false">
                    <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
                        <include name="**/*Test*.java"/>
                    </fileset>
                </batchtest>
            </junit>
        </jacoco:coverage>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you also share the the content of `<jacoco:reports>` tag?
You could have a look at mine for your usage:

```
<structure name="JaCoCo Ant Example">
            <classfiles>
                <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}" >
                    <exclude name="ut/**"/>
                    <exclude name="com/**/test/**"/>
                    <include name="com/example/**"/>
                </fileset>
            </classfiles>
            <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
                <fileset dir="${build.source.dir}" />   
            </sourcefiles>
        </structure>
```

This excludes the test packages and includes the source files. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I too face same problem, I followed this [link](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html)

```
  <jacoco:report>

     <executiondata>
        <file file="jacoco.exec"/>
     </executiondata>

     <structure name="Example Project">
        <classfiles>
          <fileset dir="classes"/>
        </classfiles>
        <sourcefiles encoding="UTF-8">
          <fileset dir="src"/>
        </sourcefiles>
     </structure>

     <html destdir="reportDirName"/>

 </jacoco:report>
```

Here the code coverage report will generate with below instruction.

```
<html destdir="reportDirName"/>
```